Passing data from the Clerk middleware to page in Next.js
I'm looking a way to pass data from the clerk middleware to the page (or auth object). I couldn't find anything yet.
export default clerkMiddleware(async (auth, req) => {
  const { userId } = auth();

  const rickAndMorty = await fetch("https://rickandmortyapi.com/api").then(
    (result) => result.json(),
  );

  // TODO: pass rick and morty to page or append it to auth

  if (isPublicRoute(req) && userId) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/dashboard", req.url));
  }

  if (isProtectedRoute(req)) auth().protect();
});

Is there a way to append data to the auth object or just pass it to the page somehow?
